# WebApps beta badge?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase

Will those of us who participated in the WebApps beta get the silver beta badge?

Will those who participated but did not fulfill their commitment get it?

If the badge will be awarded, will it be awarded to both our  'Nothing to Install' (NTI? BTW, that doesn't flow from the fingertips like SO,SF, etc does) and Area51 accounts?

Comment: Weren't beta badges awarded throughout the process? There are already 153 beta badges on WebApps... which is actually far fewer than users, isn't it? It's barely more than one badge per page of users, in fact.

Comment: Silly me, I thought I participated throughout the process.   No biggie; I wouldn't want any more bling to go to my head.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, this probably could have been posted on WebApps / NothingToInstall's meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The beta badge is for those that participated in the private beta week.  It is awarded shortly after the public beta starts.

Comment: I see you're right.

Comment: That's sad that it's only private beta. I'm active (I think) on the Mechanics SE which is in public beta, wish I could get this badge