# What are the requirements of beta badges on se sites?

Tags: support, badges, beta-badge

I tried to search here on meta, but I couldn't find any thread that answers this question.

What are the criteria for awarding a beta badge on the stackexchange sites?

Comment: @AnnaLear It's not the same criteria for the 2.0 sites, the beta badge description on the list is only for S[OFU]!

Comment: @jonsca I'm not aware of any difference between them. I just saw the meta post on your site, and I'm trying to look into it a bit.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks for looking into it, I appreciate it.  I will have to grab the other links, but there are a few cases posted around this site, the question on HIT meta, and personal experience tells me it's different than the 3 bronze badge requirement.

Answer (score 3):

For the SE 2.0 sites the requirement is:

> Actively participated in the private beta

So this means

1. You must have committed to the site so you can gain access to the **private** beta.
2. You must make a minimum number of posts. I *think* it's 10, but I can't find the reference right now (it's on one of the new sites meta). However, Gamecat has a beta badge with only 3 answers.
3. There might be a minimum number of votes, but I have no evidence of this.

The beta badge *appears* to be awarded with the your Area 51 commitment for that site being "fulfilled", but as Gamecat points out they aren't related.

Comment: The 10 posts is I think for the "following through on commitment" for area51. Lot's of people have beta badges with less posts.

Comment: @Peter - I'm not sure it is 10, which is why I said "think". I'm still trying to find the reference and will update if I find it.

Comment: @ChrisF - Sure, I was just giving a hint where the 10 posts could come from ;)

Comment: There is no direct relation between beta and fulfilled commitment. I have a beta badge on writers (3 answers, 6 upvotes) but the commitment is not fulfilled.

Comment: @Gamecat - Ah - I'll update the answer.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66219/webapps-beta-badge

Comment: Also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/115/what-constitutes-active-participation-in-the-beta-for-the-beta-badge

Comment: Note, the bounty is for an "official" answer, as I think we can all agree you're credible @ChrisF !